# What are the best practises for setting up x-ray daemon?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, logging, amazon-ecs, aws-xray

What is the best strategy to run the x-ray daemon for ~ 100 microservices running as amazon ECS stacks?[image]

- Do each microservice requires one x-ray daemon ?
- One x-ray daemon should be enough for all the micro-services?

As being the new technology and limited documentation I could not find much information regarding the best practices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two launch types for ECS https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/pricing/

It depends on which launch type you are is using. For EC2 launch type, you have the option to install X-Ray daemon on guest OS so the containers run on that OS can share one single daemon.

For Fargate, see this example and readme: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-xray-fargate